# Spark: Mapgroups on a Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying this mapgroups function on the below dataset
and not sure why I'm getting 0 for the "Total Value" column.
Am I missing something here??? Please advice

Spark Version - 2.0
Scala Version - 2.11

```
case class Record(Hour: Int, Category: String,TotalComm: Double, TotalValue: Int)
val ss = (SparkSession)
import ss.implicits._

val df: DataFrame = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
(0, "cat26", 30.9, 200), (0, "cat26", 22.1, 100), (0, "cat95", 19.6, 300), (1, "cat4", 1.3, 100),
(1, "cat23", 28.5, 100), (1, "cat4", 26.8, 400), (1, "cat13", 12.6, 250), (1, "cat23", 5.3, 300),
(0, "cat26", 39.6, 30), (2, "cat40", 29.7, 500), (1, "cat4", 27.9, 600), (2, "cat68", 9.8, 100),
(1, "cat23", 35.6, 500))).toDF("Hour", "Category","TotalComm", "TotalValue")

val resultSum = df.as[Record].map(row => ((row.Hour,row.Category),(row.TotalComm,row.TotalValue)))
.groupByKey(_._1).mapGroups{case(k,iter) => (k._1,k._2,iter.map(x => x._2._1).sum,iter.map(y => y._2._2).sum)}
.toDF("KeyHour","KeyCategory","TotalComm","TotalValue").orderBy(asc("KeyHour"))

resultSum.show()

+-------+-----------+---------+----------+
|KeyHour|KeyCategory|TotalComm|TotalValue|
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+
|      0|      cat26|     92.6|         0|
|      0|      cat95|     19.6|         0|
|      1|      cat13|     12.6|         0|
|      1|      cat23|     69.4|         0|
|      1|       cat4|     56.0|         0|
|      2|      cat40|     29.7|         0|
|      2|      cat68|      9.8|         0|
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`iter` inside `mapGroups` is a *buffer* and **computation can be perfomed only once**. So when you sum as `iter.map(x => x._2._1).sum` then **there is nothing left in *iter* buffer** and thus  `iter.map(y => y._2._2).sum` operation yields *0* . So you will have to find a mechanism to calculate sum of both in the same iteration

**for loop with ListBuffers**

for simplicity I have used `for` loop and `ListBuffer` to sum both at once

```
val resultSum = df.as[Record].map(row => ((row.Hour,row.Category),(row.TotalComm,row.TotalValue)))
  .groupByKey(_._1).mapGroups{case(k,iter) => {
  val listBuffer1 = new ListBuffer[Double]
  val listBuffer2 = new ListBuffer[Int]
      for(a <- iter){
        listBuffer1 += a._2._1
        listBuffer2 += a._2._2
      }
      (k._1, k._2, listBuffer1.sum, listBuffer2.sum)
    }}
  .toDF("KeyHour","KeyCategory","TotalComm","TotalValue").orderBy($"KeyHour".asc)
```

this should give you correct result

```
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+
|KeyHour|KeyCategory|TotalComm|TotalValue|
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+
|      0|      cat26|     92.6|       330|
|      0|      cat95|     19.6|       300|
|      1|      cat23|     69.4|       900|
|      1|      cat13|     12.6|       250|
|      1|       cat4|     56.0|      1100|
|      2|      cat68|      9.8|       100|
|      2|      cat40|     29.7|       500|
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 2):

As Ramesh Maharjan has pointed out, the issue lie in using the iterators twice, which will result in the `TotalValue` column being 0. However, there is no need to even use `groupByKey` and `mapGroups` from the beginning. The same can be acomplished using `groupBy` and `agg` which will result in much cleaner and easier to read code. And as a plus, it avoids using the slow `groupByKey` as well.

The following will work just as well:

```
val resultSum = df.groupBy($"Hour", $"Category")
  .agg(sum($"TotalComm").as("TotalComm"), sum($"TotalValue").as("TotalValue"))
  .orderBy(asc("Hour"))
```

Result:

```
+----+--------+---------+----------+
|Hour|Category|TotalComm|TotalValue|
+----+--------+---------+----------+
|   0|   cat95|     19.6|       300|
|   0|   cat26|     92.6|       330|
|   1|   cat23|     69.4|       900|
|   1|   cat13|     12.6|       250|
|   1|    cat4|     56.0|      1100|
|   2|   cat68|      9.8|       100|
|   2|   cat40|     29.7|       500|
+----+--------+---------+----------+
```

If you still want to change the names of the Hour and Category columns that is easily done by changing the `groupBy` to

```
groupBy($"Hour".as("KeyHour"), $"Category".as("KeyCategory"))
```

Comment: Great :) I forgot to think the other way around ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know this alternative approach and easy as well but as I stated in my question I was playing with this mapgroups function in order to understand